Prisma $transaction API with promises made beforehand
The examples of sequential operations show the prisma operations being generated inline to the array.
If I were to instead create the queries beforehand:
const foo = prisma.foos.update(...);
const bar = prisma.bars.update(...);
await prisma.$transaction([foo, bar]);

I'd expect that the foo and bar queries will have already been executing outside of the transaction, and prisma.$transaction is more or less empty from the perspective of the database transaction.
Is that accurate? Or is there some mechanism here that I'm not familiar with?

For posterity: while I don't know the mechanics at a low level, it seems Prisma uses a Promise-like construct that defers execution, it internally tracks queries. I didn't realize await effectively tells the runtime to just then() the Promise, which I suppose is the signal that Prisma will see to execute the quer(y/ies).
